# finalizing / post-processing chained methods

Tags: javascript, deferred-execution

Assuming I have an Array-like object which allows for chaining methods like so:

```
var ds = new DataSet(items);
var subset = ds.filter(condition1).filter(condition2);
```

Is there a way to execute code *after* the last method in the chain has been processed - without resorting to manually appending a separate `.finalize()` (or `end`/`execute`/...) method call?

I believe I've seen this before somewhere, but I don't recall the details. Perhaps futures/promises/deferreds would be of use here - but I don't really know how, since I always end up with the need to "look into the future" to determine whether a method call is the last in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the `filter` method, it may be an idea to add a finalize parameter?

```
.filter(condition,[some finalizer function]);
```

in `filter`:

```
if (finalizer){
   finalizer();
}
```

[**edit based on comment**]

Another approach could be to allow for a finalizer condition, so in `.filter(condition)`, the contents of `condition` defines the need to finalize.

Something like (I don't know the type of your condition, just making things up):

```
if (condition.match('f=true')) {
  finalizer();
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah, but that's not much different from appending a method call - I'm curious whether it's possible at all to avoid that manual step.

Comment: I appreciate your input - however, moving the finalize flag/trigger into the condition seems no different from adding a trailing method call. (conditions would be mundane things like "> 3" or "starts with 'foo'")